# Handling comment conversation

Tags: discussion

In some scenarios questioner has asked more than one question in the question's comments. I don't mind to answer those questions, but does not this look awful to have all the conversation in the comment section?

For future reference, what's the best way to avoid this in a proper way?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The best way is to ask the one asking more questions in the comment field to use the ["Ask Question"](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button on the top instead of a chat-kind-of questioning.

[image]

Comment: Much appreciated!

Comment: @PradipR. Just for the record, I have just seen this question and am the one who asked question you are talking about. If you follow the trace of the comments, you have never really answered my question which is why SharePoint is overriding bootstrap css. You have talked around the question, advised me how to override my own css file, but you never answered the question of why SharePoint is overriding bootstrap css. I have never asked another question in comments other than this one. So why are you acting like you gave me a big help and I denied that or asked more questions than necessary?

Comment: Often a solution that works in one environment doesn't work on the next. There are simply too many variables available to make an answer that is true in every environment. Giving a suggestion as an answer is good - and the community is supposed to vote on the "best" answer to a question.

Comment: @PradipR. if it's not related to my question, you should not have included it in this question. And, Exactly, as you said now, you've given suggestions (not related to my question and not related to bootstrap which was the core of my question). You gave suggestions but in your current question here you're saying: you don't mind answering my question. You didn't even know the answer to it but gave suggestions out of the scope of what I was looking for. My suggestion: if you don't know the answer, don't give clueless suggestions then come here upset about it. My comments were replies to yours!

Comment: @PradipR. I read Benny's comment. I just don't appreciate you putting my question in yours and claiming that I asked several questions in my comments, while my comments weren't questions, they were just comments on your misleading suggestions away from my original question. Stating that I asked several questions and putting that in yours here isn't a nice way in trying to look nice in the community.

Comment: @DavidHemsey We got the message. Please be chill about it and move on. Thank you!

Comment: Thanks Benny, much appreciated.

Comment: @DavidHemsey You do a great job here, and sometimes things doesn't work out as expected. But I believe with your drive you can learn and teach a lot just by participating. Ping me if you run into trouble, and I'll make sure things are fair!

Comment: Thanks Benny, how can I ping someone here?

Comment: Just use the at-sign and type the screen name. Mine is @bennyskogberg :-)

Comment: thank you. much appreciated.

Comment: Irony - (n): The accepted answer to a question about handling comment conversations... has a conversation in the comments.